# Encapsulating a class to run as a continual process with both internal and external events

Tags: c#, events, encapsulation

I have an OPC Client that I am creating.
  I am trying to encapsulate the Opc.Da.Server inside this Client with the required configuration parameters and subscriptions into a single class.

There are internal events that need to fire with in this class. I have two other custom events I created with in this class and I need to raise depending on what happens internally within the class - so my instantiating code can subscribe. 
If I don't encapsulate the Opc.Da.Server ; the Subscription DataChange event gets raised and all is cool - but I want to encapsulate so I can make things easy on myself (doesn't seem so easy right now.) None of my events fire - not the encapsulated ones and therefore also not the external one.
If I am going about this all wrong or you see a better way speak freely I think I' am still teachable - Anyway my code is :

```
public class CLIENT
{ 
    Server server {get; set;}
    Subscription subscription {get; set;}
    public CLIENT() { }

    public void StartClient(Connection connection, string[] parameters)
    {
    server = new Server(connection , parameters);
        subscription = CreateSubscriptions();
    subscription.OnDataChange +=  subscription_DataChange();
    }      
// Event is not firing 
    void subscription_DataChange()
    {
    ... do stuff something worth noting is found
        OnSomethingSpecificHappened();      
    } 
       public event EventArgs<Something> OnSomethingSpecificHappened;           
}

.. Windows Form

Form myApp
{
        Connection connection {get; set;}
        string[] parameters {get; set;}  
    CLIENT client {get; set;}

Form() {}

StartNewCLIENTe()
{
   client = new CLIENT();
   client.OnSomethingSpecificHappened +=  client_OnSomethingSpecificHappened();
   client.StartClient(connection , parameters);
}
}
```

**EDIT 5-27-2016**
I now have managed to get the events to fire once and only once. 
They are supposed to be continually updating .. it is as if my object is run and then gets disposed of. and I do not know why ..

Comment: Is the OnDataChange a custom event? You may want to look into what's called the "Observer Pattern". Try Console.WriteLine() at a few places to find where your code is getting stuck.

Comment: @Zig no OnDataChange is from the class I am trying to encapsulate - the event works fine if the class is not encapsulated with in my class, but simply as part of my form or a console app works. I am wondering if somehow it is just going out of scope and being GC'd maybe I should run it in a Thread as a long running task ?